# I like to extend the nanoframework to AURIX products, where to start?

Tags: nanoframework

I was thinking to develop my own C# compiler for AURIX, but I found that nanoframework is already existing. Therefore, I would like to extend the HAL to the AURIX device and available boards, but I do not know where to start from Can you help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

.NET nanoFramework can run without much effort on 32bit MCUs.
Your best approach is to follow one of the existing ports for Cortex-M4 and take it from there. There isn't much documentation on this, so recommend that you join our Discord community [here](https://discordapp.com/invite/gCyBu8T) and ask questions as you make your way through that.